# How to convert object query to DB query in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, dbcontext, objectcontext

I have the following code

```
String entitySQL = "(SELECT o.VehicleTypeID, (o.Engine_Capacity * cast(16039.99 as System.Double) ) " +
        " FROM CarRentalModelEntities.VehicleTypes AS o where o.VehicleTypeID = 20014) ";
        query = new ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord>(entitySQL, context);
        DataRetriever.InitializeTest(context.objectContext.MetadataWorkspace);
        DataRetriever.GetResultSet(query);
        xmlRetrievedData = DataRetriever.GetRetrievedTestData();
```

I want to use DBContext instead of Object Context. How to write the above query using DBQuery? Anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ObjectContext objectContext;
objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
query = new ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord>(entitySQL, context.objectContext);
```

We can use like this.